# AVFoundation - exposure is not changing

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation

I am trying to change the exposure duration of the camera by reading a pan gesture:

```
AVCaptureDeviceInput* deviceInput = (AVCaptureDeviceInput*)input;
NSError* error;
        
if([deviceInput.device isExposurePointOfInterestSupported] && [deviceInput.device isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeCustom]) {
    Float64 minExposure = CMTimeGetSeconds([deviceInput.device.activeFormat minExposureDuration]);
    Float64 maxExposure = CMTimeGetSeconds([deviceInput.device.activeFormat maxExposureDuration]);
    Float64 currentExposure = CMTimeGetSeconds([deviceInput.device exposureDuration]);
    Float64 delta = translation.y * (maxExposure - minExposure) + minExposure;
    Float64 newExposure = MIN(MAX(currentExposure + delta, minExposure), maxExposure);
            
    [deviceInput.device addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isAdjustingExposure" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
            
    [deviceInput.device lockForConfiguration:&error];
            
    [deviceInput.device setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeAutoExpose];
    [deviceInput.device setExposurePointOfInterest:focusPoint];
    [deviceInput.device setExposureModeCustomWithDuration:CMTimeMake(newExposure, 0) ISO:AVCaptureISOCurrent completionHandler:nil];                                                  
                                                
            
    [deviceInput.device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Then based on [this answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420577/570339) I am also observing  "isAdjustingExposure" in order to lock the exposure when it's set:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isAdjustingExposure"]) {
        NSNumber* value = [object valueForKey:@"isAdjustingExposure"];
            
        if(value && ![value boolValue]) {
            [object setExposureMode:AVCaptureExposureModeLocked];
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason this method is never called. I am not sure if this last step is necessary, but anyways this is not working because I notice that the current exposure value stays always the same, and I can also see visually that the camera doesn't adjust its exposure.

Answer (score 1):

The key name is `"adjustingExposure"` and not `"isAdjustingExposure"` and your exposure duration becomes `0/0` with the `Float64` to `int64_t` conversion in `CMTimeMake()`, so try

```
CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(newExposure, 10000)
```

for your custom exposure duration